# How does the Circle Pad Pro work?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, kid-icarus-uprising

I am trying to use the Circle Pad Pro, and while it worked for a while (and was pretty awesome), all of a sudden it isn't working anymore.

I am not sure how the thing works, so I don't have any idea what to do to try to get it to work again.

How does the Circle Pad Pro work? How does it know when it should interact with the 3DS? Would removing it when the 3DS is sleeping or paused cause it to stop working?

Also, do I have to have certain settings in game? (Such as setting move to the ABXY buttons to use the right circle pad (on the Pro) rather than the left one.)

Comment: I've played around with one briefly. When the game starts you should get an option asking if you want to use CPP. It seems that if you remove your 3DS from the bulky accessory thing while playing, a message dialog should up saying something like the infrared link has been severed and the system has reverted to the default control method. To reconnect you'll probably have to restart to the game menu.

Comment: Yeah, I never got any of that....

Comment: It's really weird. Because it uses the infrared link, it seems to be powered separately... when you wake up the system, it turn the device off (?!)... My friend who owns the accessory says that if you tap one of the triggers a couple of times before waking up the system, it seems to let you continue.

Answer (score 2):

It works when you hold down **<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>** while paused. If it doesn't calibrate, the batteries are dead.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the Circle Pad Pro in a way that causes one of the buttons to be held down (most likely the shoulder buttons), it will drain the battery.

The device does transmit IR, and it "wakes up" at the response of a button press.  The system seems to transmit IR intermittently to tell the 3DS that it is there.  After some time, this "keep alive" signal stops because the CPP went to sleep.

Every time you press a button, the IR signal lights up, the sleep timer resets, and it keeps going.